# How to get Instagram subscriptions feed without API?

Tags: json, api, curl, cookies, instagram

I write my own application, which must show my subscriptions feed photos in a grid, because I don't have a time to swipe a classic big photos on my feed. Earlier I used my own application, which used API, but as it's known, Instagram closed their API for applications, which are in sandmode.

So now I write a new application, which get the photos with cURL and cookies (it's my own application, so I use my own cookies).

And I need exactly my subscriptions feed, not my own feed.

So, at the beginning I simply received the content of main page (instagram.com) (because I have cookies, so I can get my feed simply access Instagram main page) and parsed for get their JSON data, which is raw. But problem is that I can get only first 24 photos in that way, but is there's an analog of next_id or something like this which is working with own feed, for example?

https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?max_id=1261078189229875262

But greatest way would be get an JSON at once, that there was no need to parse the html, looks like:

https://www.instagram.com/instagram/media/?max_id=1261078189229875262

Thanks a lot and long for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your instagram feed in Chrome.  Open the dev tools to the Network tab.  Scroll your feed to the bottom and inspect the API call they make when you scroll your feed to the bottom.

From what I can gather, they post all the cookies along with 2 parameters `$q` and `$ref` to `https://www.instagram.com/query/`

```
$ref = 'feed::show';
$q = 'ig_me(){feed{media.after(***$end_cursor***,***count***){nodes{id,caption,code,comments.last(4){count,nodes{id,created_at,text,user{id,profile_pic_url,username}},page_info},date,dimensions{height,width},display_src,is_video,likes{count,nodes{user{id,profile_pic_url,username}},viewer_has_liked},location{id,has_public_page,name},owner{id,blocked_by_viewer,followed_by_viewer,full_name,has_blocked_viewer,is_private,profile_pic_url,requested_by_viewer,username},usertags{nodes{user{username},x,y}},video_url,video_views},page_info}},id,profile_pic_url,username}';
```

Within the ig_me() function there's an `$end_cursor` parm.  This can be found by inspecting the page for the `window._sharedData` object.

Within `window._sharedData` you can find the `end_cursor` at `entry_data.FeedPage[0].feed.media.page_info.end_cursor`

There's also a `$count` which is set to 12 for how many images/videos to get back (I haven't played with how many you can add here).

The response from this call will give you a new `$end_cursor` at `feed.media.end_cursor` you can use for your next call.

Good luck!

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to use Chrome Dev Tools. Thanks a lot for your answer! Do you think is there are actions that Intagram can make bypassing dev tools, or we can use it at the all ways? It'll be great if it'll be so!

Comment: @Acuna Chrome Dev Tools just shows you what the browser is doing.  You can make your API calls look like the browser if you use the same headers and useragent that CDT shows you.

Comment: Hmmmm, so clever!)))